# Apply gt::html(glue::glue(()) to columns with NA values

Tags: r, gt

For a dataset `df` as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(type = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), value = c(1.2, 1.6, 
-0.3), direction1 = c(0.1, NA, 0), direction2 = c(0.0, -0.1, 1.2
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

With code below, I'm able to customize column `direction2` by conditional coloring and adding `arrow`s:

```
df %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_missing(
    columns = c('direction1', 'direction2'),
    missing_text = "-"
  ) %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(columns = c(`direction2`)),
    fn = function(x){
      `direction1` <- as.numeric(x)
      `direction2` <- as.numeric(x)
      choose_logo <-function(x){
        if (x == 0){
          gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#bfbfbf;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("arrow-right", fill = gray))
      } else if (x > 0){
         gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#CF000F;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("arrow-up", fill = red))
      } else if (x < 0) {
        gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#1F3A93;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("arrow-down", fill = blue))
      }
        else if (x == '-') {
        gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#1F3A93;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("", fill = tjd_blue))
      }
      } 
      map(`direction1`, choose_logo)
      map(`direction2`, choose_logo)
    }
  )
```

Out:

[image]

Now I hope to apply it to `direction1` as well, but since it has a `NA` value which I transformed to `-` with `fmt_missing` function, it raises an error: `Error in if (x == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.

Please note I have created an `else if (x == '-')` condition, but it's not working. Anyone could to deal with issue? Thanks a lot at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmt_missing` is only for formatting and does not change the value of `x` which will be feed into choose_logo. So it is still NA. You must catch that situation first, because e.g. `5 == NA` is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- structure(list(type = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), value = c(
  1.2, 1.6,
  -0.3
), direction1 = c(0.1, NA, 0), direction2 = c(0.0, -0.1, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df

df %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_missing(
    columns = c("direction1", "direction2"),
    missing_text = "-"
  ) %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(columns = c(`direction2`, `direction1`)),
    fn = function(x) {
      `direction1` <- as.numeric(x)
      `direction2` <- as.numeric(x)
      choose_logo <- function(x) {
        if(is.na(x)) {
          return(
            gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#1F3A93;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"))
          )
        }
        
        if (x == 0) {
          gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#bfbfbf;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("arrow-right", fill = 'gray'))
        } else if (x > 0) {
          gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#CF000F;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("arrow-up", fill = 'red'))
        } else if (x < 0) {
          gt::html(glue::glue("<span style='color:#1F3A93;font-face:bold;font-size:16px;'>{x}</span>"), fontawesome::fa("arrow-down", fill = 'blue'))
        }
      }
      map(`direction1`, choose_logo)
      map(`direction2`, choose_logo)
    }
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to show `NA` as `-` instead of itself in `direction1`?

Comment: Yes. Just do `return("-")` instead. This will overwrite the behavior of `fmt_missing`.

Comment: When I run the whole code, it throw an error: `Error in paste0("<svg ", extra_attrs, "viewBox=\"", paste0(viewbox_value, : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`.

Comment: This is because you modified my reproducible example without providing values for the variables, e.g. `blue`;)

Comment: Problem solved, thanks, but it generates: `Warning in fn(body[[col]][stub_df$rownum_i %in% loc$rows]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: This is just to remind you that there are `NA`s in your dataset. That's why it is only a warning and not an error.

Comment: For code `as.numeric(x)` and `map(`...`, choose_logo)`, is it possible we make it more concise?